# Running "composer update" within a Windows .bat file

Tags: php, batch-file, composer-php

I've recently updated my app to use composer for all its dependencies. As part of this, I've  updated my deploy script - a combo of Grunt tasks and a batch file - to include a "composer update" after doing a "git pull".

However, I'm finding that although the composer update runs successfully, none of the commands in the rest of the batch file after that line run. If I take the "composer update" line out, everything else runs fine (but of course I risk having out of date/missing dependencies).

**edit:**
Full .bat file. Without the composer update line, it runs entirely - with it, it skips out to the next part of the deploy process.

This creates a new date-stamped folder in \versions\, updates the repository & updates composer dependencies in the main repo folder, does a git checkout-index into the new version folder, uses xcopy to copy the Vendor folder with composer dependencies to the new version (because it's ignored by git) and then updates some symlinks, including the \current\ symlink which is used by IIS as the site root folder.

```
@echo off
For /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /t') do (set mydate=%%c-%%a-%%b)
For /f "tokens=1-2 delims=/:" %%a in ('time /t') do (set mytime=%%a%%b)
set date=%mydate%_%mytime%

mkdir "C:\inetpub\appname\versions\%date%"

cd "C:\inetpub\appname\repository"
git pull origin master
composer update
git checkout-index -a -f --prefix="C:\inetpub\appname\versions\%date%\\"

cd "C:\inetpub\appname\versions\%date%\\"

xcopy /E /y /q "C:\inetpub\appname\repository\www\app\Vendor" "www\app\Vendor"

del /Q www\app\webroot\files
rmdir www\app\webroot\files

cd "C:\inetpub\appname\"

MKLINK /D "C:\inetpub\appname\versions\%date%\www\app\tmp" "C:\inetpub\appname_tmp"
MKLINK /D "C:\inetpub\appname\versions\%date%\www\app\webroot\files" "E:\appname_files"

rmdir current
MKLINK /D current "C:\inetpub\appname\versions\%date%\www"

appcmd recycle apppool /apppool.name:"Localhost"
```

Comment: Please show some code.

Comment: Added .bat file contents

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Updated answer:

To get the above working properly, you have to add "call" to the beginning of any line which executes another batch file, e.g. `call composer install`

Comment: call.  Good to know!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a typo in the script. Is it possible for you to paste the script on gist or some code share? If the composer update is running correctly, then it's something in the way the script is written. Also, you should never run composer update in deployment scripts. Deployment scripts should only use "composer install"

Comment: I'll post the full code in a bit. What's the reason for using composer install vs update?

Comment: Code posted. BTW, it's never doing a fresh install of composer stuff because it deploys from a "repository" folder which has already had "composer install" run.

Comment: In case anyone else comes across this, here's the explanation of install vs update and why you shouldn't run update as part of deployment: http://adamcod.es/2013/03/07/composer-install-vs-composer-update.html

Comment: Accepted this due to the composer install/update piece. I got it working by separating my git pull and composer install into a separate batch script from the rest of my deployment.